# App writes to external storage without permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I have an app which uses the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am building the app for Android 6.0:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.my.package"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

When i now start the app and write to the external storage i do not get asked for the permission on Nexus 5 with Android 6.0 even when i did not set the permission:

[image]

Why and how is the App able to write to the external storage without permission?

Comment: The application won't write to external storage (u have to check if the app has wrote anything to the ext.storage) ,  Also it won't ask you for the permission granting until u request it by yourself

Comment: Yes ofcourse it wont ask if dont forced it. But the app would throw exceptions due to missing permissions what she is not doing. And yes. The App is indeed writing to the external storage. i checked that.

Comment: perhaps you are checking `android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE``in if statement in your class

Comment: No. Until now i dont check for any permission by myself. I just use the permission and did not grant it to the app. The app should now not be allowed to acces the external storage but that is exactly what the app is doing.

Comment: Have u tested it on a real device ?

Comment: Yes. I also tested it on a real Nexus 5 and on a Galaxy S7. Is there any "new" android 6.0 app in the play store which you know of, where i could test, if these apps behave the same?

Comment: I think facebook uses this permission.

Comment: You can try fully uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Permission grants should get cleared then. What may have happened is that your app formerly was granted permission automatically (e.g., `targetSdkVersion` was below 23), then you upgraded the app to one where runtime permisssions were needed.

Comment: It looks like you are not actually using your external storage when saving. You must be saving into the internal storage, so no permissions are required.

Answer (score 0):

> Starting in Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. This only applies to paths generated for package name of the calling application. To access paths belonging to other packages, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are required.

you can see doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))